# cURL multi giving wrong results when sending 1k+ requests parallel

Tags: php, curl

I need to make over 1k rqs simultaneously and get a responses in time less than 1 min. I'm using PHP and cURL multi. For some reason cURL doesn't work as expected and cannot handle such an amount of requests.

I'm using https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

```
$parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl(1000, [
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip',
        'Accept: */*'
    ]
]);

$resp = function($content, $url, $ch, $search) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    file_put_contents("result.csv", $info['url'] . ";" . $info['total_time'] . ";" . $info['http_code'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
};

$urls = explode("\n", file_get_contents("urls.csv"));
foreach(array_slice($urls, 0, 1000) as $url) {
    $parallel_curl->startRequest("http://" . $url, $resp);
}


$parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();
```

I set timeout to 10s.

When I open result.csv and sort by total_time descending, about half of entries is like

```
domain;total_time;http_code
http://domain1.com;0.000785;0
http://domain2.com;0.000783;0
http://domain3.com;0.00077;0
http://domain4.com;0.000761;0
http://domain5.com;0.00076;0
```

cURL gives a status code 0 and short response time, although domain exists and loads normally in the browser. When I edit urls.csv and set only one url (ie domain1.com) it works well and gives correct status 200...

Am I reaching some limit? is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: You probably reached the max number of open sockets and files your process is allowed to use. That's normally 1024.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I reaching some limit? is there anything I can do with it?

Well, you could check with `netstat` that you are not hitting the max. sockets.

Please consider that the library you are using is 4 years old and deprecated.
So, i guess, it's not your fault, that the requests are not running concurrently. According to the issue tracker other developers had the same problems with this library, see https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl/issues/20.
RollingCurlX (https://github.com/marcushat/rollingcurlx) was created to address the issue.

I'd suggest to go with Guzzle (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).
The GuzzleHttp\Pool example provided here http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests
should get you started in no time...

Comment: Thank you Jens. I have already used guzzle and found it pretty awesome, but I was trying to find alternative - guzzle seemed to be too slow for my needs (described a few days ago here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003681/php-making-many-async-guzzle-calls ) now I know that probably I'm hitting max sockets, and there's not much I can do with it. I will consider additional server resources to handle such an amount of rqs in such a minimal time, that would maybe solve my problem.

Comment: 3000 requests per minute? I tend to say that PHP isn't the right tool for this job. But it depends! On many things. For instance: On the type of request! Are you doing GET requests for gzipped content, which cause additional storage IO? Or just lightweight HEAD requests to check if a website is up? You need to optimize the request headers to ask exactly what you want, to keep negotiation time minimal. | PHP is not multi-threaded. You can have concurrent requests but in a single thread. You could try to run multiple PHP scripts at the same time; well, until it maxes out your bandwidth or CPU.

Comment: I'm asking using GET, but I will think about using HEAD. I was playing around with guzzle + pthreads with no satisfying results due to this bug https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1398 . Now I'm thinking about going with Java, but I just wanted to make sure that the goal is possible to gain using some other language. I'll play with multiple PHP scripts, thanks again for your advices!